# What statistical test should be used for pre/post data (that violate ANCOVA assumptions)?

Tags: r, distributions, generalized-linear-model, ancova, pre-post-comparison

I want to assess the effect of a treatment (control vs. ash) on a continuous variable (e.g. calcium concentrations). I have two additional grouping variables that are also both categorical: location (3 levels) and layer (4 levels). I will run post-hoc tests to determine differences (if any) between locations, and different layers will be analyzed separately. Since I have pre- and post-treatment values I was planning on running an ANCOVA to control for the pre-treatment concentrations, however a number of assumptions are violated that don't make it suitable (e.g. non-linear relationship between covariate and outcome, normality, homogeneity of variances). Therefore, I was thinking of running a GLM and because I am not very familiar with the math behind these tests yet I ran a few test models to test different distributions and link functions (gaussian and gamma with identity and log links), the best model using AIC was a gamma distribution with an identity link, but when I evaluate the model parameters my residuals look like this:

[image: model parameters litter (glm family = gamma(link = identity))]

I have a different problem when evaluating a different layer, where the residuals look better but the Q-Q plot is off:

[image: model parameters mineral (glm family = gamma(link=identity))]

Log-transforming my variables does not help in either case. I have also tried coding treatment as a dummy variable based on what I've seen online but it gives the same results. I also tried sm.ancova but am not sure that applies to this data. I have tried a Kolmogorov-Smirnov on my pre and post variables and both p values are < 0.05 for gaussian and gamma distributions. At this point I'm wondering if I'm addressing this problem correctly or am I on the wrong track completely? How do I determine an appropriate distribution? I have included a subset of the data I am using below, any help or suggestions are appreciated.

structure(list(Plot = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4,
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
8, 8, 8, 8), PID = c("1B1", "1B2", "1B3", "1M1", "1M2", "1M3",
"1R1", "1R2", "1R3", "1R4", "2B1", "2B2", "2B3", "2M1", "2M2",
"2M3", "2R1", "2R2", "2R3", "2R4", "3B1", "3B2", "3B3", "3M1",
"3M2", "3M3", "3R1", "3R2", "3R3", "3R4", "4B1", "4B2", "4B3",
"4M1", "4M2", "4M3", "4R1", "4R2", "4R3", "4R4", "5B1", "5B2",
"5B3", "5M1", "5M2", "5M3", "5R1", "5R2", "5R3", "5R4", "6B1",
"6B2", "6B3", "6M1", "6M2", "6M3", "6R1", "6R2", "6R3", "6R4",
"7B1", "7B2", "7B3", "7M1", "7M2", "7M3", "7R1", "7R2", "7R3",
"7R4", "8B1", "8B2", "8B3", "8M1", "8M2", "8M3", "8R1", "8R2",
"8R3", "8R4"), Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Ash", "Control"
), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("American Beech",
"Mixed", "Sugar Maple"), class = "factor"), pre_Ca = c(8483.76810659246,
12234.1399634832, 7932.92450973135, 9383.56494259565, 7348.35225723726,
8494.63862364107, 7619.51008323941, 8730.50411531309, 10029.5582383751,
8266.15535558031, 7624.21943180924, 8413.95324579298, 7677.65221057428,
8522.05448471619, 11827.1354299266, 12065.1898425326, 9160.1084473681,
10104.0977807935, 9541.98482954359, 9239.44995104115, 9758.46070042558,
12953.4204867559, 10634.3125105464, 11631.6220439278, 12421.6436549814,
10753.7185150164, 13431.7331492785, 13926.3872555368, 13126.6449921637,
9958.14676795406, 7819.54269532948, 9748.09009144649, 8888.0383478379,
8080.04508832869, 7872.74292676576, 8813.85009903375, 9562.21106190538,
9597.78532881581, 13216.300624113, 7769.77332220804, 7196.48944772208,
7124.15542602649, 8468.21466049975, 10790.5870856842, 8792.97720997613,
8140.78730829638, 10648.3841728365, 9822.47651236491, 10081.8694197812,
10315.2245891378, 6857.28531829282, 6815.50064546178, 9412.36708985703,
11278.9391254411, 10651.7185737934, 10081.8347613877, 13376.1370423371,
9964.42639801666, 9613.42107101119, 11556.5755912963, 8085.44665461781,
7130.66299662614, 7295.69435454984, 8602.23886534305, 12067.0426237008,
9758.0492263827, 9495.61911141576, 10217.0277564348, 11577.3714989314,
11894.096584818, 7774.9484998171, 6004.2269818691, 7852.90793212839,
8865.93476967106, 8670.11392796263, 7367.20579239188, 8461.5651741536,
9470.82064971953, 7704.57360503202, 8203.77212303817), post_Ca = c(15667.6727673979,
15138.1418952087, 13480.9141594373, 14434.4239002525, 14173.832736065,
14535.1355054448, 16755.2415474403, 13255.6404322829, 14242.705366774,
15387.957607784, 8544.24983993752, 9416.76698099421, 10049.180195687,
11507.2240936699, 11184.5735275353, 10358.8728280083, 10007.4695215208,
12611.4917792323, 11896.293862277, 10288.5918220263, 16639.5490052477,
15791.9865737253, 17201.3417641758, 15445.8546206213, 12712.1072605763,
15658.5045938394, 14791.7504464568, 15742.1287211828, 19257.598384971,
18542.5609884882, 16295.8729947232, 17252.2737581123, 18238.4316776947,
17039.1257649955, 15629.033516979, 17755.5891939467, 15089.9763543769,
14881.3015635513, 15193.1974131665, 20937.3411055086, 11760.3400735863,
8638.74415701029, 11585.5042647671, 14350.4818134341, 10516.8389372601,
12240.528038049, 8957.67280550221, 12593.518769855, 12205.4166920646,
11998.821722639, 9148.73865122313, 7776.10461665089, 8557.87887120284,
12329.2139745031, 11281.2090572376, 12601.4815096138, 7918.86187065535,
12424.9328541859, 11433.8136306576, 12745.8719366042, 13363.2245185744,
17096.0052929311, 16095.6775259985, 13188.7474448205, 16911.9702291625,
16380.0178128334, 14625.5932271234, 9859.7160183279, 17380.4648123555,
15582.5983273384, 9505.80707149924, 7995.99020741169, 9381.14366038934,
9828.07942647557, 9081.0322157827, 10568.9883042448, 10530.0743227537,
7766.62185436821, 9616.20733559481, 9700.88573644838)), row.names = c(NA,
-80L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))